# What kind of slot to be used to catch a random piece of text?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am trying to build an Amazon Alexa skill. In that, one of the intents needs a text string. It can be any random word (including names). I have do some search from a database using that word. How do I go about solving this?

I have followed the suggestion given in the accepted answer of this question - [Amazon Alexa - How to create Generic Slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819485/amazon-alexa-how-to-create-generic-slot) . But the skill is not able to read the word (or anything that sounds like it). It just identifies the intent but the slot has confirmationStatus = NONE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AMAZON.SearchQuery` to capture less-predictable input that makes up the search query.

You can find more details at https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery

Comment: Yes I was using this slot, but it wasn't able to convert speech to text correctly sometimes. So I was wondering if there was something more efficient.

Comment: hi @aniztar, if it was not converting speech to text correctly then their might be issue with our accent not with the slot type we use. Please try few more times using AMAZON.SearchQuery only. Hope this helps. Thanks